# Trying to increase the size of a sprite when it touches a pellet in Unity with C#

Tags: c#, unity

This is my first game, and I'm trying to keep it simple, so just a simple platformer that works around the size of the player's character, and the character increases in size whenever they consume a pellet. I have the character's basic movement down, but I'm coming across some errors that I'm not so sure how to fix.

The way I have it set up is that I have a script attached to an empty object called 'LevelManager' that will execute actions once it's called upon (Like 'Respawn Player' and 'Grow Player'), there is a 'Pellet' script attached to the pellet that basically calls upon the 'Grow Player' function when the player touches the pellet's collision box.

*LevelManager.cs*

```
public class LevelManager : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject currentCheckpoint;
    private PlayerController player;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        player = FindObjectOfType<PlayerController> ();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
    public void RespawnPlayer()
    {
        Debug.Log ("Player Has Respawned");
    }
    public void GrowPlayer()
    {
        Debug.Log ("Player Has Grown");
        player.transform.localScale += new Vector2(0.5, 0.5);
    }
}
```

*Pellet.cs*

```
public class Pellet : MonoBehaviour {
    public LevelManager levelManager;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        levelManager = FindObjectOfType<LevelManager>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
    void OnTiggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.name == "Player") 
        {
            levelManager.GrowPlayer();
        }
    }
}
```

Also, I'm sorry I don't have the exact errors with me, something funky happened with the editor and I'm unable to locate the window for the compile errors anymore, and when the bug report I sent get's responded to, I'll add that in to make this an easier problem to tackle.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Gamedev.SE! You are asking us to debug your code, because you did something, that caused the error view to disappear. I flagged this as "debug my code", offtopic. However, try to change the "new Vector2(0.5, 0.5);" to "new Vector3(0.5, 0.5);"

Comment: @LevelForge just change the `new Vector2(0.5, 0.5)` to `new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0);` and this should solve your problems. PS in your Pellet class it is `OnTiggerEnter2D` whereas it should be `OnTriggerEnter2D`. Also make sure that your pellets have isTrigger set to true on their colliders.

Comment: Oh god I feel so silly, thank you both for the advice, I'll make sure I don't make another 'hey debug this for me pls thx' question, I guess I was a little tired and delirious when entering the question.